# C++ sending derived pointer as argument

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, derived

I am trying to send a derived pointer to a base class's function through another one of the Base class's functions, but for some reason, it complains:
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Derived' on line 8.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Derived;

class Base
{
public:
    void getsomething(Derived *derived){derived->saysomething();} //This is line 8
    void recieveit(Derived *derived){getsomething(&*derived);}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void giveself(){recieveit(this);};
    void saysomething(){cout << "something" << endl;}
};


int main()
{
    Base *b = new Base;
    Derived *d = new Derived;
    d->giveself();
    return 0;
}
```

do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Why does base class know about derived classes?

Comment: @soon is right; this can be made to work but it is generally a bad design idea to have base classes aware of derived classes.  Perhaps a better way to implement this is to make `getsomething()` a virtual function.

Comment: Also, the `receiveit` function seems quite useless as it just calls `getsomething` with an obfuscated parameter `derived`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use forward declaration, when the compiler needs information about the class's members.

A forward declaration is only useful for telling the compiler that a class with that name does exist and will be declared and defined later.

So do like following :

```
class Derived ;

class Base
{
public:
    void getsomething(Derived *derived); 
    void recieveit(Derived *derived);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void giveself(){recieveit(this);};
    void saysomething(){cout << "something" << endl;}
};

void Base::getsomething(Derived *derived){derived->saysomething();} 
void Base::recieveit(Derived *derived){getsomething(&*derived);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to take the function definitions out of the class declaration and put them after the declaration of `Derived`. At the point you're trying to use them, the poor compiler doesn't even know what methods exist on `Derived` yet.